# Como fazer update em tabela com foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tenho tabela disciplina e tabela professor. O professor contem disciplina.
Como eu faço para modificar o nome da disciplina e automaticamente mudar nos professores tb?

Estou meio confuso sobre o uso de On update cascade e delete Casdade.. 
Ele deleta e modifica todos os filhos, mas como eu uso o update cascade na tabela disciplina se tem apenas a chave primaria?

```
public void createTableDisciplina(){
    try {
        conn.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE Disciplina(Nome varchar(50) NOT NULL primary key)");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void createTableProfessor(){
    try {
        conn.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE Professor(Nome varchar(50) NOT NULL primary key, Nome_Disciplina varchar(50) NOT NULL references Disciplina(Nome) ON DELETE Cascade, NumAulas int NOT NULL, NumFaltas int)");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arthur, você precisa consultar a Ajuda e fazer o Tour aqui do Soft, é necessário que apresente parte de seu código e também a tabela da qual está falando. Edite sua pergunta, mas primeiro veja como tratar as perguntas aqui. Bem vindo!

Comment: Obrigado, ajustei!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur, o ideal é que já que existe um relacionamento entre ambas as tabelas somente uma delas (a tabela disciplina) contenha o nome da disciplina.

O relacionamento é justamente isto... a tabela professor relaciona-se com a tabela disciplina através do id desta disciplina (imutável) e feito o relacionamento sabemos qual o nome da disciplina a qual possui o id vinculado a um professor.

Considerando esta implementação você só precisaria alterar o nome da disciplina na tabela disciplina e não precisaria se preocupar com o resto, pois o relacionamento faria a "tradução" do id para o nome ou demais colunas que você desejar da tabela disciplina.

**Editado:**

Arthur a origem do problema está na forma que você está criando a tabela.

Uma chame primária (PRIMARY KEY) não pode nunca ser um valor que você poderá alterar, ele deve ser um número incremental e único para cada linha da sua tabela, sendo assim eu criaria um campo ID inteiro em ambas as tabelas como a chave primária e criar um campo inteiro na tabela turma o qual receberia o mesmo id da disciplina que você deseja vincular, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE disciplina (
    /* NOT NULL é dispensável considerando que uma chave primaria não pode ser nula. */
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE professor (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    /*não utilizarei DELETE CASCADE pois se utilizar e um professor for removido a disciplina também será...*/
    id_disciplina INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES disciplina(nome),
    numAulas INTEGER NOT NULL,
    numFaltas INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO disciplina VALUES(0 /*id da disciplina*/, 'Português');

INSERT INTO professor(id, nome, id_disciplina, numAulas) 
VALUES(0 /*id do professor*/, 'Zé do Caroço', 0 /*id da disciplina relacionada*/, 0 /*numAulas*/);

/*Este SELECT retornará o nome do professor e de sua disciplina relacionada.*/
SELECT professor.nome, disciplina.nome
FROM professor
INNER JOIN disciplina ON professor.id_disciplina = disciplina.id;
```

Comment: Obrigado @Bruno Berman, postei o codigo.. Mas nao entendi como fazer tal relacionamento na tabela disciplina

Comment: Valeu cara me ajudou bastante!! Vou dar uma lida sobre esse inner Join..

Comment: Mas e se eu tivesse uma outra tabela que tenha professor. Por exemplo Turma, e tenha professor que tenha disciplina. E eu quiser deletar o professor, como eu faço?

Comment: Da maneira como eu coloquei você deletaria normalmente o professor porém poderia ficar com disciplinas sem um professor atribuído, no caso de só haver um professor por disciplina. O delete só vai ocorrer automaticamente nas tabelas relacionadas quando for especificado um DELETE CASCADE por exemplo: turma relaciona-se com professor (contém um campo referenciando a tabela professor) porém com condição DELETE CASCADE. Se eu deletar uma turma os professores vinculados a ela também serão removidos.